# How to json dump inside Zipfile.open process?

Tags: python, io, zip, bytesio

I am trying to write a json inside a ZipFile BytesIO process. It goes like this:

```
import io
from zipfile import ZipFile
import json

in_memory_zip = io.BytesIO()
with ZipFile(in_memory_zip, 'w') as zipfile:
    with zipfile.open("1/1.json", 'w') as json_file:
        data = {'key': 1}
        json.dump(data, json_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

It is later saved in a Django File field. However it does not `dump` the data into the `json_file`. Finds it hard since it does not report an error message.

Comment: What is `batch_zip`? Should that be `zipfile`? (by the way, probably not, I expect it should be the other way around and you want `as zipfile` to be `as batch_zip`)

Comment: Yep thats right! Sorry Typo. Edited already.

Comment: Note: you probably don't want to shadow `zipfile`, so like I said: instead of naming both `zipfile`, you're better off naming both `batch_zip`, so you can use `zipfile` (the module) later on. Also, doesn't fixing this simple fix your whole problem?

Comment: I don't get how renaming them to my typo will fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code 'shadows' `zipfile`, which won't be a problem by itself, but would cause problems if you needed `zipfile` later in your code. In general, don't shadow standard library identifiers and Python keywords.

Why it's a problem, I don't know, but it appears `json.dump` expects something from the file pointer that the file-like object that `ZipFile.open()` gets you doesn't have.

This is how to get around that:

```
import io
from zipfile import ZipFile
import json

in_memory_zip = io.BytesIO()
with ZipFile(in_memory_zip, 'w') as zf:
    with zf.open("1/1.json", 'w') as json_file:
        data = {'key': 1}
        data_bytes = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4).encode('utf-8')
        json_file.write(data_bytes)
```

Comment: By the way, I don't think the `BytesIO` part is the problem here, it's the `json_file` object returned by `ZipFile.open()` together with `json.dump` - you could update your question title, but I guess it works either way.

Comment: what is `str_data`?

Comment: It must be the 'data_bytes'. It is now working, thank you!

Comment: Oh oops - typo, apologies

Answer (score 2):

The reason original code fails is that `ZipFile` expects binary data as input, while `json.dump` expects a file-like object that accepts "text" data (`str`, not `bytes`). You may think of the object that `zf.open()` returns as if it is a file that's open with `"wb"` mode.

So the right thing to do here is to wrap the file-like object to present text-oriented output to `json.dump`. And, as any text is has to be encoded to become bytes, you have to grab the solution from `encodings` library.

So, this works:

```
import io
from zipfile import ZipFile
import json
import encodings

in_memory_zip = io.BytesIO()
with ZipFile(in_memory_zip, 'w') as zipfile:
    with zipfile.open("1/1.json", 'w') as json_file:
        data = {'key': 1}
        json_writer = encodings.utf_8.StreamWriter(json_file)
        # JSON spec literally fixes interchange encoding as UTF-8: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-8.1
        json.dump(data, json_writer, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```